# Why is Destroy not called?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, destroy

Given the following Delphi code, `Foo` is `Free`'d on `FormClose`, but `TFoo.Destroy` is not being called - and therefore `Bar` is not `Free`'d, leading to a memory leak?

Have I missed something here or shouldn't Foo.Free call Foo.Destroy at some point?

```
type
  TBar = class
  SomeInteger : integer;
end;

TFoo = class
  Bar : TBar;

  constructor Create();
  destructor Destroy();
end;

var
  Foo : TFoo;

implementation

constructor TFoo.Create;
begin
  Bar := TBar.Create;
  Bar.SomeInteger := 2;
end;

destructor TFoo.Destroy;
begin
  Bar.Free;
  Bar := nil;

  showmessage('Destroyed!');
end;

procedure TForm10.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Foo := TFoo.Create;

  showmessage('Foo created');
end;

procedure TForm10.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Foo.Free;
  Foo := nil;
end;
```

Comment: destructor Destroy(); ***override;***

Oops.

Comment: Didn't the compiler warning you about your code? It should have. Something about hiding a virtual method of the same name.

Comment: Never ignore a warning. Ignore a warning is ignoring a bug, in many cases!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must mark the signature of destructor with override.

```
destructor Destroy(); override;
```

And you should have `inherited` at the end of the destructor. But since your class is not derived from anything other than TObject I suspect that doesn't matter.

Comment: Seems we worked this out at the same time... Answer will be accepted when I'm allowed to! 

I thought I had tried override, but I put override on Create too and that gives a compilation error.

Comment: Right, Steve. `Override` goes with virtual methods. `TObject.Create` is not virtual, so you can't override it. `TObject.Destroy` *is* virtual.

Answer (score 11):

Destroy is virtual, and therefore you must override it in your descendant class.

```
TFoo = class
  Bar : TBar;

  constructor Create();
  destructor Destroy(); override; // must add override here
end;
```

Without the override, your destructor is never called, and the base class one is instead.

Comment: Thanks, got there in the end. As always it was part of a much larger project and couldn't work out what was going on. 

Funnily enough, simplifying the problem made the problem... simpler.